# Implementing code into smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I am new to frameworks. and I made simple script in php. Now I don't know how can I implement this code in smarty .tpl file.

```
// Yesterday
$hour = 12;
$today = strtotime("$hour:00:00");
$yd = strtotime("-1 day", $today);
$yesterday = date('d/m/y', $yd);

$query = "SELECT date, amount FROM yesterday_deposit";
$fetch_query = mysql_query($query);

$total_amount = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_query)){
    $day = $row['date'];

    if(($dt = date('d/m/y', $day)) === $yesterday){
        $total_amount += $row['amount'];
    }
}

echo $total_amount;
```

Comment: Read the document: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.while.tpl

Comment: That exact code will not work in Smarty. The point of Smarty is to separate templates from application code.

Comment: @deceze I know this exact code won't work. That's why I am asking what can I do?

Comment: Basically, none of this will run inside of Smarty. You'd do all this as is in PHP code, then pass `$total_amount` to a Smarty template and output it there. Smarty is only concerned with output/display, you do not do any calculations within a Smarty template.

Comment: And BTW, all those calculations can and should be done in a single SQL query instead of fetching a whole table into PHP code and doing it there. `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM yesterday_deposit WHERE date = $yesterday`.

Comment: I know none of this code will directly work in smarty.

Comment: Can I put this code in a file and then inlude it in .tpl.

Comment: No you can't, as they already told you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smarty is a template engine to separate displaying data and other operations.

What you should do in this case is:

```
// Yesterday
$hour = 12;
$today = strtotime("$hour:00:00");
$yd = strtotime("-1 day", $today);
$yesterday = date('d/m/y', $yd);

$query = "SELECT date, amount FROM yesterday_deposit";
$fetch_query = mysql_query($query);

$total_amount = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_query)){
    $day = $row['date'];

    if(($dt = date('d/m/y', $day)) === $yesterday){
        $total_amount += $row['amount'];
    }
}

$smarty->assign('total_amount', $total_amount);
```

And in Smarty template file you should simple do:

```
{$total_amount}
```

That's the way it should work. You make any calculations, get data from database in pure PHP files and display data in template files (for example in Smarty).

In the above example I assume you have created Smarty object and the variable name is `$smarty` and you display somewhere else in your code your template file.

Comment: I did not created any smarty object yet. What I did is plainly wrote above code you gave me and saved it in plugins folder. After saving I called it in .tpl file.

And still no result.

Comment: It's not a plugin, it's PHP code, so you should simple put it into normal PHP file and before `$smarty->assign('total_amount', $total_amount);` create Smarty object and after that line display your template file.

Comment: How and where can I create Smarty object?
And where should I save this file?
Can I save this file in the same folder with template or somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry, it seems you have no idea about Smarty. Have you installed it and launch demo files? If yes, put this PHP code before displaying template file and `{$total_amount}` into file you display.

Comment: Its OK and you are right I have no idea about smarty.

When I put this code on the top of .tpl file and when I call it. It gives error.

And I can't even make object.

Comment: and Yes I installed it and everything is working fine.
now I just cant add the above code to the .tpl file.

Comment: into .tpl file you add only `{$total_amount}`. The rest you add to index.php in demo directory

Comment: Will you please create smarty object of the above code?

Comment: `$smarty = new Smarty;`

Comment: Thank You. All the errors are removed. now there is no error. But value is not displaying in the template where I called it.